Apache HttpClient 5 create generic request
I am migrating from the old HttpURLConnection to the new Apache HttpClient 5 , to crate a connection in the old code I used this snippet of code
URL url = new URL(“url”);
HttpURLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod(“Post”);
conn.setaRequestProperty(header,header.value);
In the new code how I avoid to create multiple if statements and objects of HttpGet or HttpPost ?
Because in the old code I pass the http verb directly to the connection and the headers too but in the new code I must do something like this
If(“Post”) {
HttpPost post = HttpPost(url);
post.addHeader()
…
And then httpClient.execute(post)
If(“Get”)
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
get.addHeader()
And the httpClient.execute(get);
How do I avoid those if statements ?
